# Visual Basic 2008: Can command builder be used to update tables connected by data relations?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2008, multiple-tables, datarelation, oledbdataadapter

I have three tables, with two data relations connecting them (Table 1 -> Table 2 <- Table 3). 
I've been trying to use the command builder to generate the update, delete and insert commands as in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3805/Inserting-relational-data-using-DataSet-and-DataAd) but I cant seem to get this approach to work. Currently I get an error saying there is a problem with the syntax in the insert command. Also I'm using an Access database.

Is it possible to use the command builder for this or will I have to write the insert, update and delete commands myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is very vague.  Without knowing what the Insert command looks like and what the exception message says, only this section from the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf579hcz.aspx) titled "Limitations of Automatic Command Generation Logic" is worth quoting:

> The automatic command generation logic generates INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements for stand-alone tables without taking into account any relationships to other tables at the data source. As a result, you may encounter a failure when calling Update to submit changes for a column that participates in a foreign key constraint in the database. To avoid this exception, do not use the DbCommandBuilder for updating columns involved in a foreign key constraint; instead, explicitly specify the statements used to perform the operation.

Comment: Thats what I thought, thanks. Time to learn how to write my own commands then.